# Is 'synchronization' a state or a process?

Tags: meaning

I am writing a text on the process of synchronizing events. To describe this process I would have intuitively used the word "synchronization". However, the internet got me confused about the meaning of synchronization.

When googling 'synchronization' I found that the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/synchronization) states as first meaning

> "The operation or activity of two or more things at the same time or rate."

and as specification it states

> "Adjustment of a clock or watch [...]"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization) states

> "Synchronization is the coordination of events to operate a system in unison."

Finally, [WikiDiff](https://wikidiff.com/synchronization/synchrony) states

> "[...] synchronization is the state or property of being synchronized [...]"

I would consider the Oxford dictionary to be a credible source. However, the first definition seems to hint at synchronization being a state in which two (or more) things occur (repeatedly) at the same (points in) time, whereas the second definition (adjustment of clocks) indicates that synchronization is the process of synchronizing events. The phrasing of Wikipedia is a tiny bit vague, but does read more like synchronization was a process. Whereas WikiDiff clearly defines synchronization as a state.

Following another line of reasoning, nominalized verbs ending in "-ation" often indicate processes (e.g. colonization, incubation, consultation, ...). Using this approach it makes sense to assume synchronization to be the process of two or more (naturally asynchronous) events reaching a synchronous state. But then there are exceptions to this rule, like "appreciation", which *can* be the process of appreciating something, but may also be used as a noun describing the manifestation of said process (e.g. "the appreciation I received for my actions was overwhelming").

**So, my question is, what is the correct/most common/conventional usage of the word synchronization - process or state? Or is it not well-defined and I am free to specify my definition in the context of say an article?**

As additional information, if it matters, I am writing a text in the context of dynamical systems. I read through the relevant Wikipedia pages (assuming to find the conventional interpretation of synchronization there), but it seems they carefully avoided to specify what exactly synchronization means and used other words, when explicitly talking about processes or states. In academic papers, people are found to be using either meaning but I would like to see if there is a correct/satisfying answer to the question from the point of English language, before choosing my own terminology.

I welcome official/widely accepted sources, but also useful reasoning. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Aside: the Oxford dictionary is not an "official" source but a credible one.

Comment: It is a process. The word **synchronised** indicates a state.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I changed "official" to "credible".

Comment: I'd say it's neither a "state" nor a "process". It's a ***relationship***.

Comment: It can be either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say a relationship in this sense would describe a state, would you not? Or how would you describe a relationship here?

Comment: A single entity can be in a state, but for "synchronization" to have a real-world referent requires *two or more entities* to be in the relationship. But I must admit I have no idea exactly what potential "fine distinction" between ***state*** and ***process*** (and perhaps ***relationship***) is bothering you so much here.

Comment: Well, it basically comes down to whether I should write "During the (process of) synchronization, the agents in the system exchange messages." or rather "During the time before the system reaches (a state of) synchronization, its agents exchange messages." But as I understand it, actually both are fine as long as I don't confusingly change between the two meanings (e.g. "The (process of) synchronization leads the system to (a state of) synchronization.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wordnet at the Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/synchronisation) is clear (as any reputable dictionary should be) about the fact that different polysemes are used and accepted [the following re-formatted; bolding mine]:

**synchronisation** noun

- **1** *synchronisation* – the relation that exists when things occur at the same time;

  - *the drug produces an increased synchrony of the brain waves*

...
temporal relation – a **relation** involving time

- **2** *synchronisation* – an adjustment that causes something to occur or recur in unison

... the **act of adjusting** something to match a standard

.......................

The fact that the stative usage is listed before the transformational one *should* indicate that this is the more common (of course, **not** the 'more correct') usage; this is the convention used in compiling non-historical dictionaries of the English language. However, I suspect that the order is inverted here, with the more 'prototypical' usage (state rather than change) being wrongly promoted. I've noticed this on occasion, and would expect other dictionaries to order senses differently. OED, the usual ultimate reference, cannot help here as it lists polysemes in order of date of earliest printed example.

... Researching further, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronization) lists in what seems to be the 'right' order in my opinion (though it seems to conflate the transformational and a subset of the stative):

**synchronization** noun

- **1**: the act or result of synchronizing
- **2**: the state of being synchronous

Both senses are acceptable and idiomatic; either may be used in a text (or indeed both, with care), and context itself should/would normally render a precising definition unnecessary (it would look unwieldy). Of course, clarity trumps tidiness where a better solution can't be found.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, that any definition in a (renowned) dictionary is (most likely) correct. As for Wordnet, I would argue that their first proposed definition is a bit misleading, since they use "synchrony" in their example sentence, rather than synchronization. I will make sure to let the context clarify any doubt about my usage of the word. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 'synchronization' a state or a process?

Your error is to believe that a solitary noun, **absent all context,** must be describing either a state or a process and thus that its attribute is fixed.

It would have been truly helpful for you to have given an example sentence. However, the meaning of "synchronization" would have then been dependent upon the context in that sentence.

**It is impossible to overstate the importance of context in English.**

Two definitions are given as the word is used with more than a single nuance.

Comment: Yes, I should have checked more dictionaries. The sources I listed seemed to only state one possible meaning of the word, which in fact has (at least) two. The fact that the context defines the meaning, however, is not entirely obvious. But you are absolutely right that language is more complex in that regard than for instance a science. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### The process: synchronization

The verb *synchronize* means to adjust one clock to another or one process to another.

> To configure an internal time server to *synchronize* with an external time source, use one of the following methods:

[How to configure an authoritative time server in Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server)

Using this method, I would adjust my Windows machine to an external time source, say the NTP time server. The process or act of synchronization would be to instruct the operating system to query the time server and to adjust my machine's local time accordingly.

### The state: in synchrony

*Synchrony* is defined as

> Simultaneous action, development, or occurrence.
>   The state of operating or developing according to the same time scale as something else.

[Source](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/synchrony)

For a fleeting moment, immediately after synchronization, my machine would be ticking off milliseconds in *synchrony* with the NTP time server. I had just *synchronized* it, after all. But perhaps my crystal oscillator is getting old and not beating as fast as it used to. The crystal is not *in synchrony*, that is, "according to the same time scale as something else" (namely the NTP time server).